# Create a confidence interval comparison plot with sets of upper and lower bounds

Tags: r

I have 3 sets of confidence interval bounds for ordinal data from lowest to greatest in the order below.

```
lowerConfidenceInterval_var1 <- 0.944
upperConfidenceInterval_var1 <- 1.325

lowerConfidenceInterval_var2 <- 9.062
upperConfidenceInterval_var2 <- 9.482

lowerConfidenceInterval_var3 <- 7.758
upperConfidenceInterval_var3 <- 8.068
```

I would like to create a plot like this: where var1,2,3 is on the x-axis, and CIs are vertical with values on the y-axis.

[image]

From this website: https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/confidence-intervals-compare-means/

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have datapoints you can use to draw primitives: http://www.countbio.com/web_pages/left_object/R_for_biology/R_fundamentals/draw_inside_plot_R.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
lowerConfidenceInterval_var1 <- 0.944
upperConfidenceInterval_var1 <- 1.325

lowerConfidenceInterval_var2 <- 9.062
upperConfidenceInterval_var2 <- 9.482

lowerConfidenceInterval_var3 <- 7.758
upperConfidenceInterval_var3 <- 8.068

df <- data.frame(x = c("Var1","Var2", "Var3"),
                 y = c(mean(c(lowerConfidenceInterval_var1, upperConfidenceInterval_var1)),
                       mean(c(lowerConfidenceInterval_var2, upperConfidenceInterval_var2)),
                       mean(c(lowerConfidenceInterval_var3, upperConfidenceInterval_var3))),
                 ymin = c(lowerConfidenceInterval_var1, lowerConfidenceInterval_var2, lowerConfidenceInterval_var3),
                 ymax = c(upperConfidenceInterval_var1, upperConfidenceInterval_var2, upperConfidenceInterval_var3))

ggplot(data = df,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
  geom_point(color = 'blue') + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin,ymax = ymax), color = 'blue') +
  ylab("Data") + ggtitle("Interval Plot") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image: plot]